# C++/CLI Why String Equality doesn't work?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I am trying to run following C++/CLI code:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // check if we have some command-line arguments
    if (args->Length == 0) 
    {
        Console::Error->WriteLine(
            L"Error: not enough arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    array<System::String ^> ^actualArgs;
    if(args[0][0] == L'@')
    {
        String^ text;
        StreamReader^ reader = gcnew StreamReader(args[0]->Substring(1));
        try
        {
            text = reader->ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            delete reader;
        }
        actualArgs = text->Split(L'\n');
    }
    else actualArgs = args;

    for (int i = 0, n = actualArgs->Length; i < n; ++i)
    {
        String^ arg  = actualArgs[i];
        if (String::Equals(arg, L"-v"))
        {
            Console::WriteLine("Got -v !!!");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am running with argument:

```
@args.txt
```

File args.txt contains:

```
-v
... (more lines) ...
```

Debugger shows me that when executing loop over actualArgs, the actualArgs[0] == "-v", so I expect to see on the Console "Got -v !!!", but this doesn;t happen. I have tried to set the breakpoint at that console output statement and it just didn't hit. But if I pass "-v" on the command line everything works. 
The code runs in Visual Studio 2010.
Can anyone explain, what is happening and how to achieve that string equality work as I expect in this case?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `String::Equals` line, and see what the arg is actually set to. I'm betting you have a space in there, or perhaps a `"\r\n"` instead of just a `"\n"` at the end.

Comment: Every time you write a `try` block, you may just be masking a bug. Step through the code in a debugger, and see where it fails.

Comment: got "-v\r" actually. Weird Windows text files...

Comment: Thanks, @David Yaw

Comment: Split on Environment::NewLine instead, use Trim() on the single string.

Comment: *"Weird Windows text files"* - You've got this backwards, Windows does the right thing. The question is, why everyone else does it wrong. Reference: [Why is the line terminator CR+LF?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040318-00/?p=40193)

Answer (score 1):

Do your lines end with `\n`? Normally, lines end with `\r\n` in Windows. So when you remove just the `\n`, you still have an unwanted `\r` at the end of each line.

Also, I recommend you to use static method File::ReadAllLines() to read whole file into array of strings. It's shorter and cleaner than your code.